# using cordova InAppBrowser in my controller

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

In the [doc](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md) it says do like

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
```

but within my controler that code didn't responde anything, but it worked when I used window.open, like

```
$scope.Open_Video=function()
    {
        window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09R8_2nJtjg&feature=player_embedded','_blank','toolbar=yes');
    }
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Are you defining ref after deviceReady fires?

Comment: @gro no, where to define it?

Answer (score 0):

I would try waiting for the device to be ready with $ionicPlatform like this:

```
.controller('YourController', function($ionicPlatform) {

     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

          $scope.Open_Video=function()
              {
                  window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09R8_2nJtjg&feature=player_embedded','_blank','toolbar=yes');
              }
     )};
)};
```

Make sure you include $ionicPlatform as a dependency of your controller.

Hope that helps! Good luck!